# How do I customize the <datalist> active border in Chrome?

Tags: css, html-datalist

I am using Chrome `Version 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build) (x86_64)` on macOS `13.1`.

I want to customize the `<datalist>` blue border when it's active.

[image]

I have tried `:active` `:hover` and many selectors, all failed.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the :focus-visible on input. Maybe this can solve the issue.

```
input:focus-visible {
    outline: 2px solid red;
}
```